# How to create tombstone records for tables with no primary key

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, primary-key, tombstone

I am using Confluent Oracle CDC to write a source connector.
We have an old DB with no primary keys.
I can get the key from the message and put it in as the message key for Kafka.
This works fine for inserts and updates.
But when I use `emit.tombstone.on.delete=true` to handle the deletes it does not work of course, because the message is null.

So what would be a good approach to solve this problem?

The sink connector expects a tombstone record to perform the delete on a SQL Server database.

I tried to set the value of the message to null after I extracted the key from the message but, I can't get it to work. Also not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: What Oracle version are you using? If you can logically define a unique key from the  other columns, and are able to create a view on top of the table, you can add a constraint to the view and use the view instead of the table.

Comment: Now that I think about it, can the sink connector work with views?

Comment: It should, but I haven't tried it for a long while. It probably runs just a select anyway.

Comment: Finally figured it out.
So for anyone with the same problem, this fixed it for me.

On the oracle source connector I used:
key.template=${rowId}
emit.tombstone.on.delete=true

On the sqlserver sink connector I used:
pk.mode=record_key
delete.enabled=true